chromium and electron's app font bug for arabic and persian
I have an issue with Chrome and Chromium-based browsers when typing in Arabic and Persian. You can see the issue in the screenshot shown here. I've also tried Firefox, but unfortunately, the problem persists there as well.
I attempted to install a Persian language pack on Windows, but it didn't resolve the issue.
image from discord
